# error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: fopen('certificate.pem','r')

Tags: docker, go, nginx

I made a Go application. I'm using cobra library for run in terminal with just executable file.
I have a certificate.pem file under the root folder because I publish event to kafka.

In my IDE (goland) it worked. But when I move executable file to /usr/local/bin/ I'm getting error as followings:

`error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: fopen('certificate.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file Failed to create producer: ssl.ca.location failed: error:0B084002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0xa8 pc=0x412c179]`

I changed path to '../certificate.pem' and '/certificate.pem' but it does not work

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I'm stuck on the same issue when trying to configure WPA Supplicant on Ubutnu 20.04

Comment: Yes I solved it, If you give not relative path exact path it 'll work